# Mongodb populate without model parameter

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I am trying to populate some collection in another collection. However without specifying model in populate method it is not replacing with actual document. Here are my code

***cabinet.schema.ts***

```
import {Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory} from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Date, HydratedDocument, Model, Schema as MongooseSchema } from 'mongoose';

export type CabinetDocument = HydratedDocument<Cabinet>;

export const CabinetProjection = {
    _id: false,
    __v: false,
}

@Schema()
export class Cabinet {

    @Prop({
        required: true,
        unique: true
    })
    id: string;

    @Prop()
    items: [{
        item: { type: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Item" },
        status: string;
        amount: number;
    }];
}

export const CabinetSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Cabinet)
```

***item.schema.ts***

```
import {Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory} from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import mongoose, { HydratedDocument } from 'mongoose';

export type ItemDocument = HydratedDocument<Item>;

export const ItemProjection = {
    _id: false,
    __v: false,
}

@Schema()
export class Item {

    @Prop({
        required: true,
        unique: true
    })
    qId: string;

    @Prop()
    name: string;

    @Prop()
    description: string;
}

export const ItemSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Item)
```

***cabinet.service.ts***

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CreateCabinetDto } from './dto/create-cabinet.dto';
import { UpdateCabinetDto } from './dto/update-cabinet.dto';
import { Cabinet, CabinetProjection, CabinetSchema } from './schemas/cabinet.schema';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Injectable()
export class CabinetService {

  constructor(@InjectModel(Cabinet.name) private cabinetModel: Model<Cabinet>) {}

  async findOne(id: string): Promise<Cabinet> {

    const result = this.cabinetModel.findOne({
      id: id,
    }, CabinetProjection).populate({path: "items.item", model: "Item"}).exec();

    return result;
  }
}
```

With this setup it works perfectly, but if i remove `model: "Item"`, instead of Item document populated, i see object reference. Isn't `ref: "Item"` parameter sufficent?

Also my collection names are **cabinets** and **items**.

***Edit:**

Appearently the problem was in the Cabinet class structure. If i change to below code, it started to work without model parameter. Any explanation would be appreciated.

```
@Schema()
export class Cabinet {

    @Prop({
        required: true,
        unique: true
    })
    id: string;

    @Prop({ type: [CabinetItem]  })
    items: CabinetItem[];
}

@Schema()
export class CabinetItem{

    @Prop({ type: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId, ref: Item.name })
    item: Item,
    
    @Prop()
    status: string;
    
    @Prop()
    amount: number;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the biggest sources of confusion when I'm working with developers using mongoose. Hopefully this will explain.

When I set up a `ref` on a schema property I need to specify the model that I want mongoose to use to do the `populate` and replace all of my `ObjectId` with the actual documents from the referenced collection.

Here is a simple example of users that listen to songs:

```js
// User.js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    songs: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Song'
    }]
})
const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
export default User;
```

```js
// Song.js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const songSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    artist: String
})
const Song = mongoose.model("Song", songSchema);
export default Song;
```

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import User from "../models/User.js";
import Song from "../models/Song.js";
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myapp').then(()=>{
   User.find().populate('songs').then(users =>{
      console.log(users);
   });
});
```

1. Mongoose maps model names to collections names. That means when I create the model, mongoose looks for the lowercase, pluralised version of first argument in that function:

```js
mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
// "User" model --> "users" collection
mongoose.model("Song", songSchema);
// "Song" model --> "songs" collection
```

2. Mongoose now has 2 models registered that it knows about:

```js
console.log(mongoose.connection.models);
{
  User: Model { User },
  Song: Model { Song },
}
```

3. When I try to `populate` all the `User.songs` mongoose will first look at the options object of the `populate` method for the `model` parameter. If it's not there the `ref` value from the schema will be used to look for which model to use.

```js
User.find().populate('songs');
// You want to populate 'songs' huh? 
// There is no options object such as {path: 'songs', model: 'Song'}
// Let me look at your schema for 'songs':
songs: [{
   type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   ref: 'Song' //< Bingo
}]
// I have found the model you want me to use. It's 'Song', thank you!
```

4. Mongoose will now look in `mongoose.connection.models` to find that `Song` model and it can now use it to do the `populate`. Under the hood it uses functions called `modelNamesFromRefPath` and `getModelsMapForPopulate`.
5. The key here is the connections. Different connections can have different models registered. For the above `populate` to work both `User` and `Song` models would need to be registered on the same connection. In my case I used the default `mongoose.connect` connection so both my models are registered on `mongoose.connection.models`. However, some libraries use `mongoose.createConnection` and register one model on one connection and another model on a different connection. In that scenario you would have to pass the actual model and not just the name of the model as a parameter to `populate` like so:

```js
User.find().populate({path:'songs', model: Song});
```

So to answer your question "*Isn't ref: "Item" parameter sufficient?*", yes it is sufficient, normally. It may be that the `Item` model is not in scope within that class when you run `populate` or it's the `Nest.js` library that needs the model name as part of it's own model/connection management at that stage in your design. You should try to import the `item.schema` into the `cabinet.schema` to see if you still need to explicity state `Item` in the `populate`.

Comment: Didn't work. Tried to print model names with `console.log(mongoose.modelNames())` and it printed my modules correctly.

Comment: And just to clarify, i think you have typo here `mongoose.model("Song", userSchema);`

Comment: You are correct. thank you.

Comment: @Emredağıstan did you `import { Item } from './schemas/item.schema';` in the `cabinet.service.ts`

Comment: Yes, service, schema, module, triple checked all. See the edit, i moved type and ref to Prop annotation. Also changed `"Item"` to `Item.name`, even they are same, maybe that did something.

Comment: @Emredağıstan I see the edit. That will help others when they look for a solution too. Nest love prop decorators and I have seen a variety of ways to do the populate with Nest without a good explanation on a standard way. They even updated their docs to match users having to find their own populate implementations which isn't good from their perspective.